# powershell script for fixing default URL to SharePoint list column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, development, powershell

I am trying to fix default URL for Hyperlink column in share point list and getting an error. Please help to find the problem.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Configuration Variables
$SiteURL = "http://sharepoint-test/sites/name/"
$ListName = "Test list"
$FieldName= "default"

#Get the Web, List Objects
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
$List = $Web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

If($list)
{
    #sharepoint powershell update hyperlink field
    $Hyperlink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldURLValue
    $Hyperlink.Description = "Profile Picture"
    $Hyperlink.URL = "http://sharepoint-test/image/profile.jpg"

    #Add new List Item
    $Item = $List.AddItem()
    $Item[$FieldName] = $default
    $Item.Update();

    Write-host "New Item Added Successfully!"
}
```

Code returns following error:

> Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid number
>   value. A number field contains invalid data. Please check the value
>   and try again."
>
> At C:\Users\testuser\Code\test.ps1:22 char:5
>   +     $Item.Update();
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException

Answer (score 0):

You tag says "sharepoint-online". The cmdlets in your samples are for SharePoint on-prem and are typically run on the SharePoint server.

Take a look at the PNP cmdlet library for maintaining sites (webs) and lists in both SharePoint Online and on-prem.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps

For tenant admin and creating Site Collections use the SPO cmdlets:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/introduction-sharepoint-online-management-shell?view=sharepoint-ps

Here's an example using PNP to add an item:

```
Connect-PnPOnline https://yourDomain/sites/yourSite
Add-PnPListItem -List "Announcements" -Values @{"Title" = "Test Title"; "Body"="hello world"}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, Its SP 2013 environment. please suggest more

Answer (score 0):

We can use the PowerShell below to achieve it.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Configuration Variables
$SiteURL = "http://sharepoint-test/sites/name/" 
$ListName = "Test list" 
$FieldName= "default"

#Get the Web, List Objects
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
$List = $Web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

If($list)
{   
    #sharepoint powershell update hyperlink field
    $Hyperlink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldURLValue 
    $Hyperlink.Description = "Profile Picture" 
    $Hyperlink.URL = "http://sharepoint-test/image/profile.jpg"

    #Add new List Item
    $Item = $List.AddItem()
    $Item["Title"]="new item"
    $Item[$FieldName] = $Hyperlink.ToString()
    $Item.Update()  
    Write-host "New Item Added Successfully!"
}
```

[image]